# How to extract the hour and minute from a given date string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-datetime

I have the following string in Python:

```
2023-07-03T14:30:00.000Z
```

How can I extract the hour and minute from this string in the most elegant way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string "Jun 1 2005 1:33PM" into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/convert-string-jun-1-2005-133pm-into-datetime)

Comment: What's the problem? What have you tried? Sounds like a problem of computer science that has been solved before. Also: which hour do you want? The hour as given, which might be any timezone? The local hour of the PC running the code? UTC hour?

Comment: use [fromisoformat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat) to parse the string (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62769371/10197418) for Python < 3.11), then use the `hour` and `minute` attributes of the resulting datetime object.

Answer (score 1):

I think this way is the most elegant.

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
s = "2023-07-03T14:30:00.000Z"
dt = parse(s)
hour = dt.hour
minute = dt.minute
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime
dts= "2023-07-03T14:30:00.000Z"
dto = datetime.strptime(dts[:-5], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
hour = dto.hour
minute = dto.minute
```